# Is it possible to display two columns side by side in a Rails view, using Bootstrap, when looping through 'projects'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with Rails 4.0.0. Currently this is my index.html.erb for Projects:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <h3>
      <%= project.name %>
    </h3>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When a user adds lots of new projects, I would like to limit the length of the page and display additional 'projects' on the right hand column. So I would like to have two columns side by side. In html it would be just the following, but how can I make it work in Rails?

```
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">Projects...</div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">Projects....</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can't you move that div `col-lg-6` inside `.each` so that each projects will be having `col-lg-6`?

Comment: What if there are even more projects - 3 columns then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `each_slice`:

```
<% @projects.each_slice(<your_limit_per_column>) do |projects| %>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <% projects.each do |project| %>
      <h3>
        <%= project.name %>
      </h3>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# First half of projects
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <% @projects.first(@projects.length/2).each do |project| %>
    <h3>
      <%= project.name %>
    </h3>
  <% end %>
</div>

# Second half of projects
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <% @projects.last(@projects.length /2 + @projects.length % 2).each do |project| %>
    <h3>
      <%= project.name %>
    </h3>
  <% end %>
</div>
```